# Fluent Validation Entitiy Add Operation Validation Problem

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I get an error when adding with Fluent Validation. / When I try to validate with Fluent Validation, I get an error.

Although I submit the model, it puts it into validation when it is first opened.

Error Description:
Validation type names in unobtrusive client validation rules must be unique. The following validation type was seen more than once: required

Error Image :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7dcI.png)

Added Libraries : Fluent Validation / FluentValidation.Mvc5 / FluentValidation.ValidatorAttribute 8.6.1

MVCApplication :

```
    private void ValidationConfiguration()
    {

        DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;

        ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Clear();

        ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider
        {
            AddImplicitRequiredValidator = false
        });

        FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(provider =>
        {
            provider.AddImplicitRequiredValidator = false;
            provider.ValidatorFactory = new ValidatorFactory();
        });
    }
```

Class

```
[Table("Category")]
  
[Validator(typeof(CategoryValidator))]
public partial class Category
```

Category Validator

```
public class CategoryValidator:AbstractValidator<Category>
{
    public CategoryValidator()
    {
        this.CascadeMode = CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure;

        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotNull().WithMessage("Boş Geçilemez");
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Boş Geçilemez");
          
    }
}
```

View

```
     @using (Ajax.BeginForm("CategoryAddOperation", "Category", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions()
            {
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                OnSuccess = "returnPostCategoryAdd(data)",
                LoadingElementId = "loading-background",
            },
            new
            {
                @class = "CategoryAdd needs-validation",
                @area = "Admin",
                @id = "frmCategoryAdd",
                @name = "frmCategoryAdd",
                @enctype = "multipart/form-data",
                @novalidate = "novalidate"
            }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, "", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "invalid-feedback error-validate" })
                </div>
                @*<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "form-control", @spellcheck = "false" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "invalid-feedback  error-validate" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image)
                    <div class="custom-file">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Images, "", new { @type = "file", @class = "custom-file-input" })
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image, "Resim Seçiniz", new { @class = "custom-file-label", @data_browse = "Seçiniz" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Image, "", new { @class = "invalid-feedback  error-validate" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Banner)
                    <div class="custom-file">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Banners, "", new { @type = "file", @class = "custom-file-input" })
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Banner, "Afiş Seçiniz", new { @class = "custom-file-label", @data_browse = "Seçiniz" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Banner, "", new { @class = "invalid-feedback error-validate" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Header1)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Header1, "", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Header1, "", new { @class = "invalid-feedback error-validate" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Header2)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Header2, "", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Header2, "", new { @class = "invalid-feedback error-validate" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MainMenuId)
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MainMenuId, TempData["Categories"] as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "custom-select" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MainMenuId, "", new { @class = "invalid-feedback error-validate" })
                </div>*@
            }
```

Comment: Please include the error in your question, and perhaps mention what kind of error it is in your title for more relevant responses.

Comment: Please provide the code where you are getting the error

Comment: Problem Continues